# I have a build.xml file but not a pom file for a pre-existing project, are they interchangeable?

Tags: java, eclipse, pom.xml, build.xml

I'm having an issue where i've seen other people deal with it by adding a dependency to their pom file. I do not have such a file but I do have a file called build.xml that looks like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project default="create_run_jar" name="Create Runnable Jar for Project PM_DEV with libraries in sub-folder">
    <!--this file was created by Eclipse Runnable JAR Export Wizard-->
    <!--ANT 1.7 is required                                        -->
    <!--define folder properties-->
    <property name="dir.buildfile" value="."/>
    <property name="dir.workspace" value="C:/Users/SENIOR/eclipse-workspace"/>
    <property name="dir.jarfile" value="C:/Users/SENIOR/Desktop/9.9"/>
    <target name="create_run_jar">
        <jar destfile="${dir.jarfile}/9.9.jar">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="ui.MainMenuFrame"/>
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value=". 9.9_lib/activation.jar 9.9_lib/apache-mime4j-core-0.8.5.jar 9.9_lib/arial.jar 9.9_lib/commons-beanutils-1.8.2.jar 9.9_lib/commons-digester-2.1.jar 9.9_lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar 9.9_lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar 9.9_lib/GoodDatePicker-10.3.1.jar 9.9_lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar 9.9_lib/itextpdf-5.3.4.jar 9.9_lib/javax.mail-1.6.2.jar 9.9_lib/jcalendar-1.3.3.jar 9.9_lib/jcommon-1.0.23.jar 9.9_lib/jfreechart-1.0.19-experimental.jar 9.9_lib/jfreechart-1.0.19-swt.jar _9.9_lib/jfreechart-1.0.19.jar 9.9_lib/jfreesvg-2.0.jar 9.9_lib/joda-time-2.4-javadoc.jar 9.9_lib/joda-time-2.4-sources.jar 9.9_lib/joda-time-2.4.jar 9.9_lib/junit-4.11.jar 9.9_lib/orsoncharts-1.4-eval-nofx.jar 9.9_lib/orsoncharts-1.5.jar 9.9_lib/orsonpdf-1.6-eval.jar 9.9_lib/orsonpdf-1.7.jar 9.9_lib/poi-3.14.jar 9.9_lib/poi-ooxml-3.14.jar 9.9_lib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.14.jar 9.9_lib/rs2xml.jar 9.9_lib/servlet.jar 9.9_lib/sqljdbc4.jar 9.9_lib/swingx-1.6.1.jar 9.9_lib/swtgraphics2d.jar 9.9_lib/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar 9.9_lib/mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre8.jar 9.9_lib/sqljdbc42.jar 9.9_lib/AbsoluteLayout.jar 9.9_lib/eclipselink.jar 9.9_lib/javax.persistence_2.1.0.v201304241213.jar 9.9_lib/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql_2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd.jar 9.9_lib/swing-layout-1.0.4.jar 9.9_lib/commons-collections4-4.4.jar 9.9_lib/itext-2.1.7.js8.jar 9.9_lib/jasperreports-6.20.0.jar"/>
            </manifest>
            <fileset dir="${dir.buildfile}/build/classes"/>
        </jar>
        <delete dir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <mkdir dir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/activation.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/apache-mime4j-core-0.8.5.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/arial.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/commons-beanutils-1.8.2.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/commons-digester-2.1.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/commons-logging-1.2.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/dom4j-1.6.1.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/GoodDatePicker-10.3.1.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/itextpdf-5.3.4.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/javax.mail-1.6.2.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/jcalendar-1.3.3.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/jcommon-1.0.23.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/jfreechart-1.0.19-experimental.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/jfreechart-1.0.19-swt.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/jfreechart-1.0.19.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/jfreesvg-2.0.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/joda-time-2.4-javadoc.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/joda-time-2.4-sources.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/joda-time-2.4.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/junit-4.11.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/orsoncharts-1.4-eval-nofx.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/orsoncharts-1.5.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/orsonpdf-1.6-eval.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/orsonpdf-1.7.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/poi-3.14.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/poi-ooxml-3.14.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.14.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/rs2xml.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/servlet.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/sqljdbc4.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/swingx-1.6.1.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/swtgraphics2d.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/mssql-jdbc-10.2.1.jre8.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/sqljdbc42.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/AbsoluteLayout.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/eclipselink.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/javax.persistence_2.1.0.v201304241213.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql_2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/swing-layout-1.0.4.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/commons-collections4-4.4.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/itext-2.1.7.js8.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
        <copy file="${dir.buildfile}/libs/jasperreports-6.20.0.jar" todir="${dir.jarfile}/9.9_lib"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Can I use this file the same way pom files are used and add dependencies here? Or is this something completely different and I can't add my dependencies here.

Comment: No it looks like an ant file.

Comment: No, Ant and Maven are not interchangeable.  Looks like you could create a pom.xml from that build.xml by adding each JAR as a dependency.  I'd be worried about currency.  I'm betting that Ant build.xml is bringing in a lot of JARs that are old and not supported anymore.  Be sure you try this on JDK 11 at a minimum and check each dependency.

Comment: @duffymo What's the best way to check each dependency in your opinion?

Comment: Check the version available in Maven Central.  If it is not under active development, and hasn't been updated within the last year, you would be well advised to see if you can eliminate that dependency.  Unfortunately it's a manual, subjective process.   For example, I see iText dependencies.  You might have license issues.  Some of the libraries, like activation.jar, have known vulnerabilities.  You should correct those.

Answer (score 3):

Basically `build.xml` is a script for another building system called [Apache Ant](https://ant.apache.org/). It was really popular before maven and later gradle were released.

At that time dependency management as it appears in maven / gradle didn't exist, so Ant didn't offer anything like that.

However there exists another project called [Apache Ivy](https://ant.apache.org/ivy/) that adds dependency management for Ant scripts, so I believe this is your best bet if you don't want to start using (and migrate to pom.xml) and keep using Ant.

Both Ant and Ivy are still active projects, however maven and gradle over the years have become more popular in the industry.

Comment: Everything you wrote is spot on.  I wouldn't recommend Ivy, though.  Better to step up to Maven at a minimum.

Comment: Agreed, I'll also state for the OP, that all the more or less recent projects use maven/gradle these days, and Ant is probably used more in legacy applications that didn't bother to migrate to maven/gradle for some reason - I personally haven't heard about Ant projects for like 10 years in real projects :)

Comment: @MarkBramnik Ant is still used a lot to generate documentation (e.g. the popular DITA Open Toolkit is based on Ant) and Ant scripts often embedded in Maven builds via the `maven-antrun-plugin` also in recent real (what ever _real_ means) projects.